# Matplotlib set ylim to be above max(graph) plus the size of one bin on the y-axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I build a graph in matplotlib and I don't have enough space for the label above graph.

```
Purchase_Gender_Stats = bf_sales.groupby('Gender')[['Purchase']].agg(
    Mean_Purchase_by_Gender = ('Purchase','mean')
)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,4))

Mean_Gender = axs[0].bar(
    x=Purchase_Gender_Stats.index,
    height=Purchase_Gender_Stats.Mean_Purchase_by_Gender
)

axs[0].bar_label(
    Mean_Gender,
    labels=Purchase_Gender_Stats.Mean_Purchase_by_Gender, 
    label_type='edge',
    padding=3
);

axs[0].set_ylim(
    [0, max(Purchase_Gender_Stats.Mean_Purchase_by_Gender) + 
     np.std(Purchase_Gender_Stats.Mean_Purchase_by_Gender)]
)
```

What I would like to do is to add more space to ylim by 2000 in this point, but not to do it manually, but to do it automatically. Or it would take the difference between nearby y ticks or it would divide the max value into equal parts and add it to ylim. In my code above I added np.std, and it doesn't always work. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The simplest approach to obtain something similar, is `axs[0].margins(y=0.1)` (the default is `0.05`).

Answer (score 0):

Get the current limits with `ax.get_ylim()`, and adjust from there.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=range(0, 5), height=np.random.random(size=5))
ax.set_ylim([0, ax.get_ylim()[1] + 1.76])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem for me here is that I'm not sure if the number of ticks is constant. Based on your solution I came to this solution ...+ axs[0].get_yticks()[1]. Works perfectly.  axs[0].set_ylim([0, max(heigh_value) + axs[0].get_yticks()[1]])

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, based on the answer found this solution:

```
axs[0].set_ylim(
    [0, max(Purchase_Gender_Stats.Mean_Purchase_by_Gender) + axs[0].get_yticks()[1]]
)
```